# What are nodes in cloud computing?

Tags: cloud

In cloud computing, what do people mean by...

- nodes?, and
- traversal of nodes?

Is it just two different computers which are communicating, or two different entities, or a server and a client?

Please explain. I tried googling this topic but I only get results about nodes in data structures.

Comment: I google nodes in cloud computing and it shows me first result as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_%28networking%29 .Are you sure you google it?

Comment: It's the same thing a node has *always* been in a computer network. Don't let them confuse you by calling it a "cloud".